# Config file for IIS Http Module

Tags: c#, iis-7, config, httphandler

I wrote a dll for an IIS Http Handler. I then added this dll to the gac. Now I want to add in a single config file for this dll.
Where and how do I do this.

I initially tried creating a config file called mydll.dll.config, but that didn't seem to work.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you could embed a `mydll.config` as a resource into your dll or just add it to `machine.config`.

Comment: Adding it as a resource won't help me, as any change to it, would still require the project to be recompiled.
In the end, I added it to machine.config, and it worked perfectly!
Thank you!